# Converting function React component to class component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-component

I'm trying to add a login page to my existing app. Following along this tutorial  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-login-authentication-to-react-applications

Got stuck in step 3. My app is a class component, while in the tutorial it's a function component.

How can I convert this to a class component?

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import './App.css';
    import Dashboard from '../Dashboard/Dashboard';
    import Login from '../Login/Login';
    import Preferences from '../Preferences/Preferences';
    
    function setToken(userToken) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
    }
    
    function getToken() {
      const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
      const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
      return userToken?.token
    }
    
 
    function App() {
      const token = getToken();
    
      if(!token) {
        return <Login setToken={setToken} />
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="wrapper">
          ...
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

I've tried as below, but it says getToken is not defined inside of a render.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Login from '../Login/Login';
import Preferences from '../Preferences/Preferences';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
         token: undefined
}

this.setToken = this.setToken.bind(this);
this.getToken = this.getToken.bind(this);
}

setToken(userToken) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
}

getToken() {
    const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
    return userToken?.token;
  }


  render() {
  const {token} = getToken(); /* In this line getToken is not defined */
     
  if (!token) {
  return <Login setToken={(newToken) => this.setState({ token: newToken })} />
   }


  return (
      
       <div className="pomodoro-clock">
    
       </div>
        );
  }
```

I see in the original code, getToken and setToken declared outside of an app. I've tried this, but anyway, getToken is not defined .

I can provide the full code if needed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the functions members of the class, then you need to refer to it using `this.getToken()`, not just `getToken()`;

```
render() {
  const {token} = this.getToken();
```

Though since the `getToken` and `setToken` functions don't make any reference to `this` they don't actually need to part of the class. You could keep them outside the class, and refer to them the same way the function component refers to them:

```
function setToken(userToken) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
}
    
function getToken() {
  const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
  return userToken?.token
}

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const {token} = getToken();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm, I see, thanks! Can u explain why do we need to put token inside curly braces in the render: const {token}?

Comment: Those curly braces are an example of [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). `const { token } = getToken()` does the same thing as `const token = getToken().token` . `getToken` is apparently returning an object with a `.token` property, and the code is getting that property and assigning it to the variable `token`.